# How can I prevent reordering of a dictionary on jquery $.getJSON()

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I'm retrieving a dictionary using JQuerys' $.getJSON();
The data sent across the wire is

> {"0":"Item1","82":"Item2","1":"Item3","4":"Item4"}

I then try to build a select list using a loop

```
for (var key in data) {
    var item = new Option(data[key], key);
    target.options.add(item);
}
```

The select list ends up in the wrong order because the order the values come out of the dictionary is in the order of the value of the key. In other words they come out in the following order

```
0: Item1
1: Item3
4: Item4
82: Item2
```

I was expecting in the order they came across the wire.

```
0: Item1
82: Item2
1: Item3
4: Item4
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

The properties of an object (as that's what it really is) doesn't have a specific order.

Use an array instead:

```
[{"id":"0","name":"Item1"},{"id":"82","name":"Item2"},{"id":"1","name":"Item3"},{"id":"4","name":"Item4"}]

for (var item in data) {
  var opt = new Option(item.id, item.name);
  target.options.add(opt);
}
```